# Data does not load in hive hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am trying to run my data transformation job which written in Scala with hive queries inside.

Below is my configuration of hortonworks (ambari) hadoop.

```
HDP-2.5.3.0
HDFS         (ver.2.7.3)
YARN         (ver.2.7.3) 
MapReduce2   (ver.2.7.3)
Tez          (ver.0.7.0)
Hive         (ver.1.2.1000)
Spark2       (ver.2.0.0)
```

When I run my program in cluster mode, data does not load in hive but same Scala jar when I ran on only on master node then it work perfectly. It inserts data in hive tables.

There are no exception reported in cluster mode, so I can not figure out what is exact issue.

How can I find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: please post command that you are using to run this job in cluster mode...

Comment: Nikhil - I would recommend posting clear questions with all the details so that it can be answered without being asked for further details. Please post the dummy code that you are trying to execute and logs, if possible.